# Retrieving the ID of a token_def<>

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

Is it possible to retrieve the ID of a token defined in the lexer like this: `token_def<> tok;` from inside the semantic action of a Spirit parser.

What I'm trying to do is to use the token ID of every operator (like +, -, *, etc.) and retrieve a corresponding name for that operator from inside the parser semantic action (like, add, subtract, times, etc.)

As far as I understand, in a production like:

> toks.symbol >> toks.plus >> toks.symbol;

if `toks.plus` is or type `token_def<> plus;`, _1 will refer to the first `toks.symbol` and _2 will refer to the second `toks.symbol`. Is that true? If so, how can I access the middle token (just to retrieve the ID)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin lazy placeholder [`lex::_tokenid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_semantic_actions.html#spirit.lex.abstracts.lexer_semantic_actions.lexer_semantic_actions_using_phoenix), see docs:

- [Lexer Semantic Actions Using Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_semantic_actions.html#spirit.lex.abstracts.lexer_semantic_actions.lexer_semantic_actions_using_phoenix)

I adapted the [second word-count sample from the tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/tutorials/lexer_quickstart2.html) to print the token ids on the fly:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct distance_func
{
    template <typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
    struct result : boost::iterator_difference<Iterator1> {};

    template <typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
    typename result<Iterator1, Iterator2>::type 
    operator()(Iterator1& begin, Iterator2& end) const
    {
        return std::distance(begin, end);
    }
};
boost::phoenix::function<distance_func> const distance = distance_func();

template <typename Lexer>
struct word_count_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    word_count_tokens()
      : c(0), w(0), l(0)
      , word("[^ \t\n]+")     // define tokens
      , eol("\n")
      , any(".")
    {
        using boost::spirit::lex::_start;
        using boost::spirit::lex::_end;
        using boost::spirit::lex::_tokenid;
        using boost::phoenix::ref;

        // associate tokens with the lexer
        this->self 
            =   word  [++ref(w), ref(c) += distance(_start, _end), phx::ref(std::cout) << _tokenid << ";" ]
            |   eol   [++ref(c), ++ref(l), phx::ref(std::cout) << _tokenid << ";" ] 
            |   any   [++ref(c), phx::ref(std::cout) << _tokenid << ";" ]
            ;
    }

    std::size_t c, w, l;
    lex::token_def<> word, eol, any;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef 
        lex::lexertl::token<char const*, lex::omit, boost::mpl::false_> 
        token_type;

    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    word_count_tokens<lexer_type> word_count_lexer;

    std::string str ("the lazy moon jumped over the brazen mold");
    char const* first = str.c_str();
    char const* last = &first[str.size()];

    lexer_type::iterator_type iter = word_count_lexer.begin(first, last);
    lexer_type::iterator_type end = word_count_lexer.end();

    while (iter != end && token_is_valid(*iter))
        ++iter;

    if (iter == end) {
        std::cout << "\nlines: " << word_count_lexer.l 
            << ", words: " << word_count_lexer.w 
            << ", characters: " << word_count_lexer.c 
            << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::string rest(first, last);
        std::cout << "Lexical analysis failed\n" << "stopped at: \"" 
            << rest << "\"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;65538;65536;
lines: 0, words: 8, characters: 41
```

Comment: Thanks sehe. So this is how to access the token ID from the lexer semantic actions. Is there a way to access it from the parser semantic actions?

Something like: tok.symbol >> tok.plus >> tok.symbol [ std::cout << "plus_token_id" << std::endl ];

Comment: @HaithamGad [Here's the third sample of the Lex tutorials adapted](http://ideone.com/YqoDo) to use SA to print token ids from withing parser SA. I don't see how that would add value, since the token is already known at the time you match it?

Comment: I see that in this case, word is defined to be token_def<std::string>. Would this code work if word was defined to be just token_def<>? As far as I understand, tokens defined like this are not accessible by a placeholder in the parser semantic action. Is that true?

Comment: @HaithamGad, no that is not true. There just won't be an exposed type (unused_type: you can't -usefully- get the value of the token) but that is irrelevant. Obviously the ***token*** exists, and that is what holds the Id.